# Add Tooltip to tabPanel with HTML in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, tooltip, tabpanel

I am trying to add tooltips/popovers for a Shiny application, and use this question as example
[Add Tooltip to Tabs in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953873/add-tooltip-to-tabs-in-shiny)

The problem is I can't use `HTML()` to modify the title. I need to have a line break `<br>`between lines, and text with bold, color. Normally it worked for all of titles I used except this one.

Any thoughts?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    navbarPage(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(span("Tab 1", title = HTML(
          "<span style='color: red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;'>Test</span>
           <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'> File</span> <br>'Another test'"
        )
       )),
      tabPanel("Tab 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab 3"),
      
    )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can't set a `title` attribute using a `HTML()` function, I believe you can achieve your desired outcome by adding a `data-toggle` attribute to the tab `span`, and then using a little Javascript/jquery to set the `span`'s tooltip properties to include `html: true`:

```r
library(shiny)

title_html <- "<span style='color: red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;'>Test</span>
<span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'> File</span> <br>'Another test'"

shinyApp(
    ui = navbarPage(
        tags$script(HTML('
           $( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
                $(\'span[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip({
                    html: true
                });      
           });'
        )),
        
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(span("Tab 1", title = title_html, 
                          `data-toggle`="tooltip")),
            tabPanel("Tab 2"),
            tabPanel("Tab 3")
        )
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
        
    }
)
```

Then, if you want to further customize the appearance/behavior of the tooltip, you can add other options (beyond just `html: true`) to that script tag, as listed in the [Bootstrap tooltip docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options).